# How to transfer WinRAR key to Linux

Tags: linux, rar, license-key

### Situation

I have bought [WinRAR](https://www.rarlab.com/) license some time ago and have the `rarreg.key` file. I would like to continue using RAR program on Linux licensed with my key.

---

### Question

Is it possible to transfer the key to Linux? If it is, where should I put the key?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### `order.htm` contains answer

> WinRAR, RAR for Unix and OS X now use the same registration key
>   format, so you can use the same key with current WinRAR and RAR versions
>   for all mentioned platforms.

so **Yes, it is possible.**

---

Further, it also states where to copy the key:

> If you use RAR/Unix and RAR for OS X, you should copy `rarreg.key`
>   to your home directory or to one of the following directories:
>   `/etc`, `/usr/lib`, `/usr/local/lib`, `/usr/local/etc`. You may rename it
>   to `.rarreg.key` or `.rarregkey`, if you wish, but `rarreg.key` is also valid.